# React/Redux dispatch action from root component?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, redux, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use firebase with React-Native / Redux I need to dispatch an action every time a user signs in or signs out. How can I dispatch an action from the root component?

```
class App extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
            // Dispatch Action here
            } else {
            // Disptach Action here
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Router />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        this.store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                this.store.dispatch(...);
            } else {
                this.store.dispatch(...);
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={this.store}>
                <Router />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

And do not make any side effects inside `render()` function. It must be pure function.

Comment: It's best not to create the store in a component constructor but to just use Provider from React-Redux. Creating a store inside a component is not the Redux Way.

Comment: @DDS This is main App component so therefore there is no difference initialize store in constructor or outside component.

Answer (score 2):

Use the redux `connect` and `mapDispatchToProps`... find the documentation [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options). Connect will still work with the root component. Then in your `componentWillMount` you can reference the action from your components props passed to it via `connect`

Comment: I've tried this, it does not work I get the following error "Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root componenet in  a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(App)"

Comment: Move the provider to be static and put your auth stuff on a parent component that uses connect.

Comment: I'm getting the same error I'm using react-native-router-flux, could that have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this problem. Shouldn't be the best way, but it works.

Make your request for authentication on the Root Component (App.js) setting loggedIn to true or false. (Im using firebase authentication on the example below)

With that done, you pass the state as a prop to a Component (InitialSetUp.js) and there you can set the state using Redux.

On the InitialSetUp, you act like the root, rendering the app itself.

Following you can find the example.

App.js

```
...

const store = createStore(reducers, 
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && 
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());

export default class App extends Component {
state = { loggedIn: null};

componentWillMount() {
firebase.initializeApp({
...YOUR SETUP
});

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
if (user) {
this.setState({ loggedIn: true});
} else {
this.setState({ loggedIn: false});
}
});
}

renderInitialView() {
return  <InitialSetUp loggedIn={this.state.loggedIn}/>
}

render() {
return (
<Provider store={store}>
<View style={styles.container}>
{this.renderInitialView()}
</View>
</Provider>
);
}
}
```

InitialSetup.js

```
...

class initialSetUp extends Component {

renderInitialView() {
this.props.setLogged(this.props.loggedIn);
return  <Navigation />
}

render() {
return (
<View style={styles.container}>
{this.renderInitialView()}
</View>
);
}
}

export default connect(null, actions)(initialSetUp);
```

Good Luck o/